# ¿Cómo manualmente asignar endpoint address url a partir de un textbox?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, api

Tengo una aplicación formulario en C# que consume un servicio Web. Como parámetros mandatorios tengo el ApiKey.

Esta aplicación se conecta al endpoint address. Lo que intento hacer es sin tener que modificar a cada instante el archivo `app.config`, es poder modificar el `endpoint address` a partir de un textBox en el cual el usuario pueda indicar antes de poder hacer la llamada del servicio.

Esto es lo que estoy intentando hacer pero no da resultado al executar el código:

```
WS.DashboardSoapClient client = new WS.DashboardSoapClient();
client.Endpoint.Address = new System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress(textBox2.Text);
```

¿Cómo podría lograr esto?

Muchas gracias.

Comment: No puedo editar, pero "ednpoint" debe ser "endpoint" (disculpen, no se mucho español)...que error te veo?

Comment: Que mensaje recibes cuando defines la url, hay algun mensaje de error? si pones la url en el browser resuelve correctamente ?

Comment: Hola. ya resolvi el problema. fue error mio. Los sitios de prueba que intentaba llamar no lograba contactarlos. Agregue una ruta la cual ya podia conectarme y ya funciona. Gracias de todas maneras